# Labels in Out-of-time validation

Tags: classification, validation, labeling

I have a binary classification problem and I use out-of-time validation to validate my models. My question is regarding the label. There is a lag in identifying the correct label.

Simplified example:

Train: years 2014 and 2015

Test: 2016

The correct label (1) for an observation of end 2015 is observed in 2016. My opinion: the label in the training set for this observation should be 0 (default value), because it was not observed in 2014 or 2015 and a model in production also would not have this infromation. So the expectations about model performance could be overly optimistic. Is this correct?

Thank you!

Comment: You should not include future data that was not known at the time of measurement, that will result in optimistic results as you put it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider yourself looking at this observation when your system observes it at the end of 2015. You can inspect its feature values, but the label field is empty, as it has not yet been observed. At this moment in time, the observed label of this instance is neither 0 nor 1, it is a missing value and should be treated as such.

> My opinion: the label in the training set for this observation should
>   be 0 (default value), because it was not observed in 2014 or 2015 and
>   a model in production also would not have this infromation.

Here you implicitly use an estimate ('default') instead of the observed value and you should be aware of this. Unless your classification model accounts for uncertainty of the class labels, you might want to stick to using only *ground truth* - that is, information you know to be true due to its direct observation.